# JQuery mobile - can I detect scrollstart on the page content rather than the document?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, document, domdocument

I am trying to detect scrollstart using JQuery mobile, if I use the following it works:

```
   $(document).bind("scrollstart", function() {

        console.log("scroll start detected");

    });
```

However this logs every time the entire page is scrolled. I want to detect the scroll on the page content only rather than when the whole page (document) scrolls.

I have tried various attempts like as follows:

```
   $("#myContent").bind("scrollstart", function() {

        console.log("scroll start detected");

    });

   $("#myPage").bind("scrollstart", function() {

        console.log("scroll start detected");

    });
```

But nothing I try seems to work except using the document. Is it possible to detect the scrollstart on anything other than the document?

Answer (score 0):

you must put your selections in a quotation:

```
$('#myContent').bind("scrollstart", function() {

        console.log("scroll start detected");

    });

   $('#myPage').bind("scrollstart", function() {

        console.log("scroll start detected");

    });
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just poor pseudo code by me, in my application they are in quotations

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs you can do this with [Steady.js](http://lafikl.github.io/steady.js/) with the `scrollElement` option.

Comment: Do you know if it's not possible with JQuery? I would like to avoid adding subsequent libraries if possible but if it's not possible using JQuery I will have to research them.

Comment: I haven't used the library myself, but it's only 5.34 KB if you're worried about size. I guess you could look at their source (only 200 lines) and pick the parts you'd need and recreate it in jQuery.